# pandastable layout tkinter

Tags: python, dataframe, tkinter

Dear Python community,

flowing my trying to make a GUI desktop application to trait a data from Excel file and display the result on the table by using Tkinter and pandastable packages
Currently, I did all of the work I set above and I didn't arrive to set that table in the exact location, you may find below my try:

```
proc=df2[df2['Module'].isin(mdl)]

print(proc)

frame=Frame(window)
frame.pack()    
table=Table(frame)
pt=Table(frame,dataframe=proc,showtoolsbar=True,showstatusbar=True,rows=50,cols=11,width=1500,height=700, editable=True, enable_menus=True,x=20,y=50)

pt.show(proc)
```

Even when I set x,y to move the table to that location I don't get any result as you can see in the picture below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQQHY.png)

Any solutions, please
Thank you for your support
Kind regards
Reda

Comment: `pandastable` use `grid` manager to lay out the components inside `frame` internally, so `x` and `y` options are ignored.  You can use `padx` and `pady` in `frame.pack()` to offset the table instead.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you, it's worked very well
the result is printed properly, just I need to set wrap text in cells.
Any solutions please

Comment: `pandastable` does not support wrapping of cell text currently.